# GKE / running php apps / exposing via nginx or apache?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Not that much experienced in php, currently running a php app

The cluster uses an nginx ingress load balancer

The php container currently uses nginx (FROM that one https://hub.docker.com/r/wyveo/nginx-php-fpm/), so the pod is exposed via nginx

I'm having some weird behaviours by using this image, so I had in mind to give apache a shot, in case it would provide a more stable result

That is, it does not change the game; is there any other ways to run a php app in such context ? What would be the best way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the official images?

For safety is better to use official images rather than other ones.

Check the php official repo, they have a version with apache installed.

I am not a php expert either, but the configurations I have made usually use apache to handle requests.

The official repo: 
https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Check the tags that use apache. There are versions in stretch and alpine.

Comment: it is indeed always better to first investigate that way; thx a lot for pointing this out!